# Qual é a diferença entre offset().top e position().top no jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Qual é a diferença entre `$(el)offset().top` e `$(el).position().top` no jQuery?

Percebo que alguns casos os resultados são diferentes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A diferença é que o [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) é relativo ao documento, enquanto o [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) é relativo ao ancestral posicionado (*) mais próximo.

Por exemplo:

```js
var b = $('#b');
var offsetTop = b.offset().top;
var posTop = b.position().top;

$('p').text('O div de dentro está a ' + offsetTop + 'px do topo do documento, e a ' + posTop + 'px do div de fora')
```

```css
div {      
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>

<p></p>
```

---

(*) Um ancestral [posicionado](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#def-cb) é qualquer elemento acima na árvore do DOM que tenha `position: qualquer-coisa-exceto-static`.

Comment: Você quer dizer os acenstrais que usam `position:relative`?

Comment: Os que usam `position: qualquer-coisa-exceto-static`.

Comment: Foi bom ter perguntado isso aqui então. Eu estava com o conceito totalmente errado :|

Answer (score 2):

Isso depende do contexto que o elemento está. O position retorna a posição em relação ao pai, e o offset faz o mesmo em relação ao documento. 
Obviamente, se o documento é o pai offset, que é geralmente o caso, estes irão ser idênticos.

Se você tem um layout como este, no entanto:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 200; left: 200;">
     <div id="sub"></div>
 </div>
```

Em seguida, o deslocamento para a sub será de 200 : 200 , mas a sua posição será 0 : 0.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset